# Mootools: Events in element constructor

Tags: javascript, mootools

I'm creating a new element in Mootools which has events, thus:

```
var div = new Element('div', {
id: 'dynamic',
'class': 'injected',
styles: {
    color: '#f55'
},
html: 'Hong Kong Phooey, number one super guy. Hong Kong Phooey, quicker than the human eye. He\'s got style, a groovy style, and a car that just won\'t stop. When the going gets tough, he\'s really rough, with a Hong Kong Phooey chop (Hi-Ya!). Hong Kong Phooey, number one super guy. Kong Phooey, number one super guy. Hong Kong Phooey, quicker than the human eye. He\'s got style, a groovy style, and a car that just won\'t stop. When the going gets tough, he\'s really rough, with a Hong Kong Phooey chop (Hi-Ya!). Hong Kong Phooey, number one super guy.',
events: {
    click: function(event) {
        alert('clicked');
    },
    mouseenter: function(event) {
        var self = $('dynamic');
        self.setStyle('color', '#090');
    },
    mouseleave: function(event) {
        var self = $('dynamic');
        self.setStyle('color', '#f55');
    }
}
});

div.inject(document.body);
```

Is it a bad technique to get the div with self = $('dynamic') in each event? I've tried

```
mouseenter: function(event) {
        this.setStyle('color', '#090');
    }.bind(this)
```

thinking that "this" would refer to the element I was constructing. But instead it refers to the global window.

Am I going about things the right way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well - this in the context of the constructor before the actual element exists won't work, as you have discovered - it will scope window or anything bound up the scope chain from where you use the constructor.

having a selector self = selectorbyid is not very great either if you repeat it often and care about performance.

the fastest way to do this would be to reference `event.target`, which will be the div--or to break apart the element constructor in two and add the events when div is an object and you can bind it.

downside to using `event.target` is if you programatically want to call it by `div.fireEvent("click")` which will fail as the event won't be passed on. but you can do `div.fireEvent("click", { target: div });` and get around that

of course, since div is a scoped hoisted variable you already have, you can just do:

```
mouseenter: function(event) {           
    div.setStyle('color', '#090');
},
mouseleave: function(event) {
    div.setStyle('color', '#f55');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you could use `event.target`

```
events: {
    mouseenter: function(event) {
        event.target.setStyle('color', '#090');
    },
    mouseleave: function(event) {
        event.target.setStyle('color', '#f55');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot pleasedontbelong, that's a nice economical way of doing it.